# how to diagnose azure problems

Tags: azure

I've recently starting experimenting with azure cloud hosting and my web app had about 10 minutes down time today.

I'm not sure why and I was wondering what tools I have available for determining the cause of the downtime.

Answer (score 1):

You have application logs and site logs. Basically application logs are information produced by your web app code. You can use instrumentation to trace call and exceptions in your appliction. Site logs are information produced by the web server and you can see error messages and failed request tracing without instrumenting your code. You won't have relevant information now since by default all diagnostics are turned off but if it happens again you know where to look for.

Here's how to enable and visualize this information.

**Enable diagnostics logging for web apps in Azure App Service**

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/